# Cache name not displaying inside cache storage

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I have defined workbox route to cache image but it was not visible inside cache storage. However, the image is cached and serve from `disk cache` even in offline mode.

I have followed the documentation and did everything mentioned there. But still, the cache is unavailable.

[image]

[image]

**edited**

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
     /\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/,
     new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
            cacheName: 'images-cache'
     })
  );

   workbox.routing.registerRoute(
     new RegExp(/.*user\/getAll/),
     new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
      cacheName: 'api-cache'
     })
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a little misconception :)

Your first image shows only the names of the caches saved/cached in the Cache API. If you click "api-cache" or "workbox-precache-v2...", you'll see what's *inside* that cache on the right. Those are cache names, not the contents of the caches.

Your second image shows a network request that was made for the file 1327-m.jpg. That file was found from the browser's disk cache and served from there. In offline mode the network request would not show status code 200 if it wasn't successful – you would also not see the image on the page. So what is this *disk cache*? The browser has different sorts of caches. The network panel – shown on your second picture – does NOT show you the caches provided by the Cache API ("api-cache" etc.). Instead, the network panel shows you where the browser actually got the file. In this particular situation it got it from disk which means it read it from the hard drive. Other possible values include eg. "memory cache" and "ServiceWorker". The browser stores the files in different places and the info on the network panel shows you where it got them back to be used on the page.

Does this make it clearer for you?

(So what is memory cache? That's a faster cache, it has got its files in RAM. Disk is *slower* than memory and sometimes the browser decides to put the files on the disk instead of the faster memory cache. You *cannot* control this yourself, browser is in full control. It usually uses heuristics like the freshness and the recentness of use of the file.)

Comment: thanks, I have edited my question to make it more clear. I have two routes defined in `sw.js` file. Both the route got their custom name but 'images-cache' is not been displayed in the inside cache. So what is bothering me is why `api-cache` is been displayed but `image-cache` won't